# Can I use Eclipse to make an icon that is 512x512 (for Google Play)?

Tags: android

I created my own icon for my app using Eclipse (Manifest->Application->Icon etc) and this created the same icon for all different phone screens. However, I now need that same icon for the Google Play market and it needs to be 512x512. Is it even possible to enlarge that icon using Eclipse?? Thanks.

Comment: Why use Eclipse? An icon can be made in any image editor. I'm not trying to bash, I'm honestly curious.

Comment: I just followed the tutorial tbh and it done a good enough job. In future i might try out another image editor though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse creates it in your project root, name: `ic_launcher-web.png` or something like it.

Comment: Yeah, however it is much smaller than the required image that Google Play need. They need 512x512, my largest in drawable-xhdpi is like 96x96

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but you can use [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html?utm_content=bufferbcc6a&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer)

I used it to make plenty of action bar icons, notification icons and just general icons. I think it is a great tool all android developers should be aware of :)

Comment: It just seems silly that Eclipse would have the option to make an app icon, but not take into account the market needs a much larger one. I'll use that one you linked tho, cheers EDIT: It turns out it is available, next to the Android manifest file.